# Show higher resolution on small screen (scale down)

Tags: display, framebuffer, pitft

I am using the PiTFT by Adafruit [(see product page)](http://www.adafruit.com/product/1601). It connects as a framebuffer device with 320x240px. I do not need to say that this is a bit low to display full web pages.

Is there a way to create a kind of virtual display that displays 640x480px and scale it down to the display.

- The text does not need to be readable
- I already have tried `startx -dpi 40` but this only scales down the text.
- Browser zoom is no alternative as it destroys most pages css

Anyone have some X11 magic for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A workaround I did is to connect my little screen using the RCA video, but I'm afraid your screen doesn't have that connection. That way, the rPi sent a signal of 480p screen, even tough my screen is the same resolutions as yours.